# Error message reads timber not activated or scheduled maintenance

Tags: wordpress, timber

This is a problem that happens frequently. Sometimes my website says it is briefly unavailable for scheduled maintenance and sometimes it says Timber not activated. Same applies to the WP dashboard/ editing site. This means I can't even reactivate Timber when necessary. I contacted the guy who built the site and he said "I've re-enabled the Timber plugin and removed the maintenance message WordPress was throwing up.
It may be worth speaking to GoDaddy and seeing why there are issues updating plugins?
There seems to be something wrong with the site's folders and files permissions."

I spoke to Go Daddy and they said there is nothing wrong on their end, so they suggested bringing the problem up with Timber. Anyone experienced something similar/ know whats happening or if I can contact Timber directly?

Thanks, Patrick

Comment: Hi Patrick, welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't enough info to go on. What did GoDaddy tell you, specifically? Did they look at your file permissions? They may be basing their claim on the fact that they are not in charge of the file/folder permissions on your server. You are. So both may be true: there's nothing wrong "on their end" **and** there's something wrong with permissions. If you and your web guy don't know how to find out what the permissions are and how to fix, you need to hire a professional. I'm sorry I can't be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure this never happens, you can create a file in `/wp-content/mu-plugins/` that will force Timber to always load, let's pretend it's called `load-timber.php` inside it:

```
<?php

require_once('../plugins/timber-library/timber.php');
```

That should do it! This forces WP to load Timber ASAP. While the error you're encountering shouldn't happen at all, this should ensure everything loads as expected